# Disable progress output aws s3 sync without disabling all output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is there any way to disable the

```
Completed 1 of 12 part(s) with 11 file(s) remaining...
```

progress output with the `aws s3 sync` command (from the aws cli tools).

I know there is a `--quiet` option but I don't want to use it because I still want the `Upload...` details in my logfile.

Not a big issue, but creates mess in the logfile like:

```
Completed 1 of 12 part(s) with 11 file(s) remaining^Mupload: local/file to s3://some.bucket/remote/file
```

Where `^M` is a control character.

Comment: There's a `--only-show-errors` option, but it will also suppress "Upload...". Related: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/519

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[As of October 2017](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/519), it is possible to only [suppress upload progress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) with `aws s3 cp`, `aws s3 sync` and `aws s3 mv` by using the `--no-progress` option:

> --no-progress (boolean) File transfer progress is not displayed. This flag is only applied when the quiet and only-show-errors flags are not
> provided.

Example:

```
aws s3 sync /path/to/directory s3://bucket/folder --no-progress
```

Output:

```
upload: /path/to/directory to s3://bucket/folder
```

Comment: `aws s3 mv` also works with `--no-progress`.

Answer (score 8):

You should use `--only-show-errors` flag while running the command. Also, you would want `--no-progress`. This is going to minimize the logging. 
More specs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Answer (score 5):

I had a quick look at the CLI tools code and currently it is not possible to disable that message.

Comment: It is now possible with `aws s3 cp /path/to/filename s3://path/to/filename --no-progress`; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57527597/10376320

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the message completely. You can only delete by editing but when you run again, it would show up again.