# handle self-deleting console outputs in unix\shell\bash

Tags: bash

I want to download a huge file from s3 to a server so I'm using nohup.
Problem is, the process outputs "self-updating reports", which are cool in the terminal but are horrible when written to a file as a single long line.

My questions are:

1. How should I handle this output to avoid a 84MB text file of just one line?
2. Given that I have such a file, how can I read its "bottom line" effectively?

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919469/disable-progress-output-aws-s3-sync-without-disabling-all-output

Comment: Fair enough, thou I had trouble looking for it since it was too specific. I was sure there should be some more general answer as to how to deal with this style of carriage return problem (from curl, installations, s3 or whatever)
The answer is also termed more generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "self-updating" text is just a carriage return character, which when printed to the terminal moves the cursor back to the beginning of line, allowing you to overwrite any previous text on the line.

To remove everything up through the last carriage return character,

```
awk '{ sub(/.*\r/, ""); }1' file
```

or the same with any regex tool (`sed 's/.*\r//' file` would work if your `sed` recognizes the nonstandard `\r` escape).

Some tools have an option to turn off progress updates; if you are using the standard `aws s3 cp`, try adding the option `--no-progress`.